# installing a jdk and android studio after downloading its zipped folder

Tags: java, android, jdk, oracle

this is a common error whenever i try to install jdk, jre and android studio :

```
error processing package oracle-java7-set-default (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
 oracle-java8-installer
 oracle-java7-set-default
```

Any help please??

Comment: Which command you are using  to install it.I  am getting bit confused with the title("after downloading its zipped folder").

Comment: I downloaded the zipped folder but on installing i used commands that i got from online not the folder so it brought those errors.

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer oracle-java7-set-default

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio

Then update package lists and install the script:

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install android-studio

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing problem  with oracle-java installation from ppa, you can install   `openjdk-7-jdk` from Ubuntu official repo.

- First remove all instance of oracle-java*

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge oracle-java*
  ```
- After it execute

  ```
  sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
  ```

**You can also download and install the latest JDK   from Oracle site.**

Download it  from

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

- After downloading open terminal and cd to the folder where you have
  downloaded the above file (say ~/Downloads)

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads/
  tar zxf jdk-8u25-linux-x64.tar.gz 
  sudo mv jdk1.8.0_25/ /opt/
  cd /opt/jdk1.8.0_25/
  ```
- Now enter following command to make it your default java

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/java 1
  sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/javac 1
  sudo update-alternatives --set java /opt/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/java
  sudo update-alternatives --set javac /opt/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/javac
  ```
- Now test your current java version using

  ```
  java -version
  ```
- It should show your java version

  ```
  java version "1.8.0_25"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
  ```